# Replaced Tub Spout, now water pressure in the shower is weaker than before. Is there a water leak?

Tags: water, bathtub, water-pressure, water-damage

I hired a handyman to replace my Tub Spout with this one here: https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-5-1-2-in-Decorative-Tub-Spout-in-Brushed-Nickel-10316/202562828#product-overview.

Now the water pressure in the shower head is weaker than before. Does does implied a faulty installation? I now afraid the water might get kicked back into the drywall from the spout/copper pipe, can cause water damaged.

I'm living in a condo, there is no way I can check the bottom unit at this point. What should I do?

Comment: First thing I would check would be to remove the shower head and clean any filter in there. It is possible that some debris, plummers tape, etc is blocking flow.

Comment: When you activate the shower by pulling up on the diverter does any water continue to run out of the faucet?

Comment: In a condo, much better to hire a plumber (=license and insurance) than a handyman (=???) because if the handyman screws up and is uninsured, the problems caused are going to be your responsibility. Depending on condo rules and/or jurisdiction, it might even be *required* to do that, for that reason.

Comment: @HoneyDo When I pull the diverter, all water goes to the shower.

Answer (score 0):

To get your old flow back you need to remove the Tub Spout and remove the restrictor that forces it to meet the new flow requirements for tubs and showers. Be forewarned this may be illegal in your area proceed at your own risk. I had a similar problem with my showers.